# подчеркивает строку Graph в баттоне. не могу понять что не так

Tags: c#

```
    double x1, x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,k,b,d;
    string s;
    string res;
    void Graph(double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3, double k, double b, ref string s)
    {
        k = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2);
        b = y1 - (k * x1);
        d = (k * x3) + b;
        if (y3 == d)
        {
            s = "Точки лежат на одной прямой";

        }
        else
        {

            s = "Точки не лежат на одной прямой";
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        x1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        x2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        x3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        y1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        y2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
        y3 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
        Graph(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, ref res);
        label7.Text = res;
```

Comment: В объявлении метода - 9 параметров, в вызове - 7.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: решила проблему, спасибо большое